# How to: project based authorization in Hudson

Tags: hudson

i was wondering how the "projectbased matrix" authorization should work in Hudson.

Due to the help text, it should enable one to give users different accesses to different projects.

But if I enable this I get the same table as normal matrix authorization and I don't see anywhere to set on/off privileges to specific projects.

How can I set different privileges to people to specific projects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you set those rights on the project themselves, i.e. on the "Configure" page of the project (not on the global "Configure System" page)

[image]

<sup>the red sign is there only because "vonc" is not an actual user in our referential ;)</sup>

---

[Peter Schuetze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204042/peter-schuetze), who backs up "my belief", points out in the comments to the **[Role & Strategy Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Role+Strategy+Plugin)**, where you can associate roles to jobs and to users:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your believe is correct. That's how I do this and it even works. ;)

Comment: There is an Role Strategy Plugin. You can than define roles that you can use for your project. http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Role+Strategy+Plugin

Comment: argh... wanted to add more :-) really superb ... thanks for this detailed and pictureous reply !!!